What are the tax implications of having a rent-free lodger
First, this is all for a piece of fiction I am writing and takes place in summertime Colorado, not far outside  Denver.
A young woman (eighteen) has been kicked out of her parents house after her extremely religious  father catches her in the midst of behavior he profoundly disapproves of.
Another young woman, also 18, who is married and in the early stage of her first pregnancy sees the first crying outside a local library and decides to help, thinking here is someone who can help her with stuff around her very large house and also once her baby comes. Her husband (who is much older, late 30s) happens to be extremely wealthy thanks to the lawsuit after his parents were killed by a drunk taxi driver smashing through the side of their house at 2am one morning while he was away at college.
What implications are there to this couple giving the first young woman lodging rent-free? My first idea was for him to simply write up a rental agreement and then give her a letter where the actual rent is waived. But then he starts wondering about the taxes (which he doesn't care about a great deal) and also wanting to make sure she can't claim some sort of life tenancy in his property (which he does care about). They (especially the wife) do not want this to be any kind of employment arrangement (the wife is much more after a friend).
The first young woman definitely won't be getting anything sent to her parent's house. This almost-bogus rental agreement idea came up as a way for her to get a permanent address and start getting officialdom to recognize her existence again. She already knows she's going to need to get a new copy of her birth certificate, but without ID that is difficult, and without an address ID is difficult and the circle goes on.

Hard to give tax advice based on a novel. There are several issues in this story, rent-free lodging is the least problematic of. I suggest the wealthy gentleman call the tax adviser and the attorney he, surely, has on retainer and discuss the labor law issues, gift tax issues, liability issues, etc.

That is exactly who he is on the phone with, I'm trying to figure out what he's told.

Call your own tax advisor and offer to take them out for dinner in exchange for picking their brains? I wouldn't want to bet my book on Internet advice....bl Having said that, if there's no income if any kind there's no income tax. And this is small enough that I wouldn't worry about gift tax. So as far as I can see, to his falls in the category of having/being a long-term guest, with no tax consequences for either. But IANALoTC.

I'm assuming that you are trying to write a novel with some consistency with the real world regarding taxes. I understand that everything of the story in the question is hypothetical. The answer below is also toward the hypothetical situation in the novel. It is not answering for a real-world situation and is not a legal advice in any sense.
First, whether there's a rental agreement or not, this is a gift from the wealthy couple to the first young woman. "A gift in the statutory sense, on the other hand, proceeds from a "detached and disinterested generosity, out of affection, respect, admiration, charity or like impulses." Commissioner v. Duberstein, 363 U.S. 278 (1960). Federal income tax law generally looks at the substance of the transaction, rather than the form. Therefore, the presence of the rental agreement won't change the tax treatment.
Second, I don't think there's a concern on life tenancy for the wealthy couple. I guess you get the impression of the possibility of a life tenancy from adverse possession. However, it does not satisfy the hostility and exclusivity requirements, which are required by all states including Colorado. However, if you can modify your story slightly by setting the first young woman to stay in one of the couple's houses that the couple never visits or takes care, and let the young woman live their as if the young woman were the owner, the story would be a lot more authentic when it comes to adverse possession.
Third, I can't say much about the the possibility of an unexpected employment relationship, but commonsense tells me that this is really unlikely.
But! If you can modify the story to that the wealthy couple requires the young woman to help out with their housekeeping, then the first and third points can become murky and interesting. I believe you can make up nice stories here if twists of legal disputes are a big selling point of your story.

Thank you. Like I said, the life tenancy issue is simply a (paranoid) concern of the guy's, something he thinks of and doesn't want to have come about even accidentally. His lawyer can simply tell him "don't worry about it" and it'll mostly calm him. They don't exactly require it of her, but she does end up doing a lot of the cleaning. The wife enjoys cooking but hardly anyone actually enjoys cleaning up afterward. It definitely does not work for my story to have her live somewhere else.
